# asp.net web app - check user exist in Active Directory group

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, active-directory-group

I have asp.net web app, how to check the current logged in user (client) is in specific Active directory group.
Thanks

Comment: Great answer but for future reference received {"Unknown error (0x80005000)"} when implemented. Fixed by adding domain to following line: var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this the following method. Just change it according to your needs...

```
public List<string> GetGroupNames(string userName)
{
    var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    var src = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userName).GetGroups(pc);
    var result = new List<string>();
    src.ToList().ForEach(sr => result.Add(sr.SamAccountName));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Leniel, Thanks for the quick reply. i just copied your code ran on simple web app. this gave an error - {"Unknown error (0x80005000)"} ,  am i missing anything ?

Comment: @Yogesh: check this: http://www.lansweeper.com/forum/yaf_postsm8519_Active-directory-computer-lookup-Unknown-error-0x80005000.aspx This is a pretty broad error. If you search for this  Unknown error in Google you'll get a lot of possible problems...

Comment: This requires **.NET 3.5** or higher - doesn't work on 2.0 or 3.0. Also: the user that the web app is running under needs to have permission to at least read the AD.

Comment: @Yogesh: **where** (on what line in the code) does this error happen when you debug through??

Comment: var src = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userName).GetGroups(pc);

Comment: I created one AD group(local) and assigned user, trying to get that group, i think that is where i lost. Please correct me if i am wrong, the AD group must be on the domain not on local box.

Comment: now I used exisitng group where i am the member and i used this line of code flag = User.IsInRole("ADGroupName"); .... Bingo! and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Only works in ASP.NET but similar calls are available for windows apps)

```
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("RoleName"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this helps
Harvey Sather